# Euclidean Distance Between All Points in an 2 Vectors

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

If I have two single-dimensional arrays of length M and N what is the most efficient way to calculate the euclidean distance between all points with the resultant being an NxM array?  I'm trying to figure this out with Numpy but am pretty new to it so I'm a little stuck.

Currently I am doing it this way:

```
def get_distances(x,y):
    #compute distances between all points
    distances = np.zeros((len(y),len(x)))
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(x)):
            distances[i,j] = (x[j] - y[i])**2
    return distances
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say your arrays are each "representing a line in space"? Are they distances along some axis or something else?

Comment: Actually I misspoke, they are actually y values of the line in space.  I will correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have 1-dimensional positions :

```
a = np.random.uniform(50,200,5)
b = np.random.uniform(50,200,3)
```

you can just use broadcasting:

```
result = np.abs(a[:, None] - b[None, :])
```

with the result being:

```
array([[ 44.37361012,  22.20152487,  89.04608885],
       [ 42.83825434,  20.66616909,  87.51073307],
       [  0.19806059,  21.97402467,  44.87053932],
       [  8.42276237,  13.74932288,  53.0952411 ],
       [  8.12181467,  30.29389993,  36.55066406]])
```

So the i, j index is the distance between point i from array 1 and point j of array 2

if you want the result to be NxM in shape you need to exchange `a` and `b`:

```
result = np.abs(b[:, None] - a[None, :])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  When I tried your method I got different results then with what I imagine is a less efficient way. I have included my code for comparison.  This is vs:  diistances = np.abs(x[:,None] - y[None,:])

Comment: I think you forgot that you have to take the square-root after squaring the difference. But since it's one dimensional taking the absolute is much faster and completly equivalent.

Comment: @chemnteach - Maybe I mixed up want you wanted in shape. I've edited the answer if you want N x M result shape. I read it the other way around. But it's just swapping ``a`` and ``b``.

Comment: My problem was that I switched a and b.  Thanks so much for your assistance!